# Postgresql syntax error at or near "+"

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I got the following postgresql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_address() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$

DECLARE row_count INTEGER;
DECLARE max_id INTEGER;
DECLARE key_ INTEGER;

BEGIN
SELECT count(*) FROM ADDRESS INTO row_count;

IF row_count = 0
THEN SET NEW.id_address = 1;
ELSE SELECT count(table_name)
 FROM FREE_KEYS
 WHERE table_name = 'ADDRESS' INTO row_count;

 IF row_count = 0 
 THEN SELECT max(id_address) FROM ADDRESS INTO max_id;
      SET NEW.id_address = max_id + 1;

 ELSE SELECT min(free_key) FROM FREE_KEYS WHERE table_name = 'ADDRESS' INTO key_;
      SET NEW.id_address = key_;
      DELETE FROM FREE_KEYS WHERE table_name = 'ADDRESS' AND free_key = key_;
 END IF;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

i don't understand why the assignment operation returns the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "+"
LINE 700:        SET NEW.id_address = max_id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main errors in your function:

1. There is no SET in PL/pgSQL. Assignment is done using `:=`
2. The `INTO` clause for a variable has to come after the list of columns in the SELECT statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_address() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$

DECLARE row_count INTEGER;
DECLARE max_id INTEGER;
DECLARE key_ INTEGER;

BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) 
      INTO row_count --<< the INTO has to be after the column list
  FROM ADDRESS;

  IF row_count = 0
  THEN 
    NEW.id_address := 1;  --<< there is no SET in PL/pgSQL
  ELSE 
    SELECT count(table_name)
      INTO row_count   --<< the INTO has to be after the column list
    FROM FREE_KEYS
    WHERE table_name = 'ADDRESS';

    IF row_count = 0 
    THEN 
      SELECT max(id_address) 
         INTO max_id  --<< the INTO has to be after the column list
      FROM ADDRESS;

      NEW.id_address := max_id + 1;
    ELSE 
      SELECT min(free_key) 
         INTO key_    --<< the INTO has to be after the column list
      FROM FREE_KEYS 
      WHERE table_name = 'ADDRESS';

      NEW.id_address := key_;
      DELETE FROM FREE_KEYS WHERE table_name = 'ADDRESS' AND free_key = key_;

    END IF;
  END IF;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

But the biggest problem is the function itself. This is not going to work in an environment with more then one concurrent transaction. You can't "generate" new IDs using `select max()` it simply won't work unless you lock the whole table for every insert.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help that worked for me. I'm trying to manage primary keys using triggers on each of my tables. I have a table called FREE_KEYS which contains all the primary keys deleted from tables to make them reusable for the next inserts. But as you said with concurrent transactions it will maybe not work.